# How do exclude first four rows and first four columns when pivoting data,

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

[image]

I would like to transform this data to following

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include the data directly using e.g. `dput()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @stefan I will include code and data, thanks

Comment: df <- data.frame(col1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA, 'A', 'B'),
                 col2=c('year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4', 10,20))

#This should be converted to 

df1 <- data.frame(col1=c( 'A',  'B'),
                  col2=c( 'year1', 'year1'), 
                  col3=c( 'year2', 'year2'),
                  col4=c( 'year3', 'year3'), 
                  col5=c( 'year4', 'year4'), 
                  col6=c( 10, 20))